# Extract frequency of oscillation from data

Tags: python, trend

I have a plot coming from a numpy array which looks like this:

[image]

As it can be seen, there is kind of an oscillation trend in the data.

I wonder if there is any "pythonic" way to get an estimation of this frequency of oscillation.

Comment: Man....I think the question is quite straight forward....

Comment: it is also voted to be unclear and it is also because you are not showing what you have  tried

Comment: Show me the unpythonic way and then I will tell you.

Comment: Take a look at [Fourier analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis); numpy has some relevant functions.

Comment: this is very similar to pitch extraction in audio. it's not pythonic vs. non-pythonic; you're probably looking to do an FFT (=Fourier Analysis); the highest bin should have the frequency in it. a simpler but more error prone option might be to filter out the outliers, find local minima/maxima, and just take the time between two minima or maxima... very rough but might be enough.....